# Can my caregiver help me during Embarkation for a cruise?

Tags: health, cruising, accessibility

On Aug. 5th, I will be heading R/T from Miami to Southern Caribbean.

Although I have cruised before, I have never done so with a handicap. This time, I will be boarding as temporarily-disabled; bringing my rollator / walker. My caregiver will be flying to Miami.

I do not want to have any problems, like fatigue, and start rolling backward during embarkation. Is it possible for my caregiver to come aboard with me? She will not be staying onboard.

Comment: That would depend on the cruise line. What did they say when you asked them?

Answer (score 3):

We needed something similar for our daughter.  We contacted the cruise line to let them know, and they put us down as priority assisted boarding.

We had a separate check-in at the pier (so we didn't have to line up with the masses which would have been difficult), and once checked-in a crew member came to assist us with our boarding of the ship as necessary.

It's not uncommon for cruises, and they have procedures in place already to help passengers such as yourself

Answer (score 2):

You will have to ask the cruise line directly. Typically non-passengers are not allowed on board but they can make exceptions.

This being said: most cruise lines are well equipped to assist handicapped and elderly passengers. You can most likely get boarding assistance directly from the cruise company, you will just have to ask.

Answer (score 1):

So, the answer to you question is technically yes but they would much rather provide boarding assistance them selves.  In practice, it's just like the airport.

You should contact the cruise line directly as soon as possible to make arrangements.  Explain exactly how much assistance you need but be prepared and expect to also explain this at the pier.

When you get to the pier, check your luggage with the porters and ask them where to check in for assistance.  They should know, if not, there are plenty of terminal staff and cruise line employees around.

Here's some more in for on the accessibility options: [Royal Caribbean answers cruise ship special needs and accessibility questions](https://www.royalcaribbeanblog.com/2022/08/24/royal-caribbean-answers-cruise-ship-special-needs-and-accessibility-questions)

You can also ask about accessible shore excursions and considerations for the ports of call.

Happy cruising!